# Construct a tree given pre and inorder or post and inorder

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, tree

I want you to pick my code apart and give me some feedback on how I could make it better or simpler. For a full tree (all nodes with 0 or 2 children) it works deterministically:

```
public class Construct {

    private TreeNode root;

    private static class TreeNode {
        TreeNode left;
        TreeNode right;
        int item;

        public TreeNode(TreeNode left, TreeNode right, int item) {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
            this.item = item;
        }
    }

    public void treeFromPreOrderAndInorder(int[] pre, int[] inorder) {
        if (pre == null || inorder == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Your tree is not accurate");
        }
        if (pre.length != inorder.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Your tree is not accurate");
        }
        // should this be overloaded + testing.
        root =  treeFromPreOrderAndInorder(pre, 0, inorder, 0, inorder.length - 1); 
    }

    /**
     * Private functions are not overloaded.
     * Check binary0.
     */
    private TreeNode treeFromPreOrderAndInorder(int[] pre, int pos, int[] inorder, int lb, int hb) {
        if (lb > hb) return null;

        // step 1: fetch parent
        int parent = pre[pos];
        // step 2: fetch position
        int parentPosInorder;
        for (parentPosInorder = lb; parentPosInorder <= hb; parentPosInorder++) {
            if (inorder[parentPosInorder] == parent) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (parentPosInorder > hb) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Your tree is not accurate");
        }

        // proof in diagram : https://bitbucket.org/ameyapatil/pointstonote/commits/a3137e1e5c9f40f28c53b9c62e27f0e8bf81a000
        int numElemsInLeftSubTree = parentPosInorder - lb;

        /**
         * Basically absolutely same as construct Balanced BST from sorted array
         * with this extra junk to be added.
         */
        int leftParentPosPre = pos + 1;
        // proof in diagram : https://bitbucket.org/ameyapatil/pointstonote/commits/458d044f96226e8df1c47775dbe3c8c5ad9ecce4
        int rightParentPosPre = pos + numElemsInLeftSubTree + 1;

        // step 3: recurse
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(null, null, parent);
        node.left = treeFromPreOrderAndInorder(pre, leftParentPosPre, inorder, lb, parentPosInorder - 1);
        node.right = treeFromPreOrderAndInorder(pre, rightParentPosPre, inorder, parentPosInorder + 1,  hb);

        return node;
    }
```

Comment: Is the tree reconstruction necessarily deterministic? If the inorder array is `[8, 8, 8, 8]` and the preorder array is also `[8, 8, 8, 8]`, then what should the result look like?

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm looks good to me. Regarding the code, here are a few points:

1. You don't need to overload the function. Semantically it's a tree builder, and probably the `private` function can be termed as `buildTree`.
2. The following condition should throw the `IllegalStateException` instead of `IllegalArgumentException`:

   ```
   if (parentPosInorder > hb) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Your tree is not accurate");
   }
   ```
3. You can make the code generic by using a generic data type for the node value.  Accordingly, the API will be extensible enough.